# MySQL can only log in as root, even after creating new users with their own database

Tags: mysql

**Problem:**

I just set up a Debian Wheezy installation for testing, and installed the LAMP packages and PMA.

I can log in as root with my pre-defined password, create/edit/delete both databases and users. The problem comes when I create a new user 'something', set a password for it, and grant it all privileges on a table 'something' (same as the username). Upon connecting, it denies access to the user.

**Details:**

- Host: `localhost using MySQL 5.5.24-8`
- Creating user: `CREATE USER 'something'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '***';GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'something'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '***' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS`something`;GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON`something`.* TO 'something'@'%';`
- Checking privileges: `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'something'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*92F9DAF5F5129554509489FDB6A433510223C799';`
- Result: `Access denied for user 'something'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

**More Info:**

I use this same exact procedure for the Squeeze distribution, and it works perfectly. Is there a chance it's *because* of Wheezy, or something else? I need to continue using Wheezy because of the updated packages (for this test server -- the others work fine), so 'just use Squeeze' is not an option. Note: I HAVE tried `flush privileges;` to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think I have found the problem:

You created the access for *something@'%'* but not for something@'localhost'

*%* is not localhost for MySQL, you have to make another addition.
This is why the error message is complaining about *something@'localhost'*

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//adding-users.html

Comment: Thanks, worked. But I'd still like to know why it works in Squeeze and not Wheezy with the wildcard `%` host.

Comment: Yes and No, you have to add localhost prior %  (yes two additions for the same user) it is mentioned and the link I have provided.

Comment: Look in the link provided with the line starting by "It is necessary to have both accounts" it may answer all your questions